# JUnit Theory datapoints as Collection elements

Tags: java, junit, junit-theory

I am testing a method which takes a `List` parameter. For example:

```
public String foo(List<String> list) {
    return list.contains("A") ? "OK" : "Failed";
}
```

I am using JUnit 4 Theories to test with every possible list up to a length of three, from a small set of potential elements:

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class TestFoo {

    @DataPoints
    public static List<String> potentialElements() {
       return Arrays.asList(null, "A", "B");
    }

    @Theory
    public void foo_returns_OK_when_list_contains_A(
        String val1, String val2, String val3) {

        List<String> list = Stream.of(val1, val2, val3)
            .filter( x -> x != null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        assumeThat(list, hasItem("A"));

        assertThat(foo(list), is("OK"));
    }
}
```

This works, but feels like a bit of a workaround.`val1,val2,val3` is a bit of a code smell. If I wanted to test with longer lists, it would soon become very unwieldy.

I would prefer to be able to write my Theory as:

```
@Theory
public void foo_returns_OK_when_list_contains_A(List<String> list) {

    assumeThat(list, hasItem("A"));

    assertThat(foo(list), is("OK"));
}
```

(Perhaps with some annotations)

Of course I'm aware that I could write my own `ParameterSupplier`, which would build a `List<List<String>>` -- this would need to generate all the possible combinations. I don't need answers that explain how to do this.

What I want to know is, since the `Theories` runner already knows how to create cartesian products of datapoints, is there a neater way than I've used, to populate collections consisting of those products?

Comment: There is no specific notion of cartesian product in JUnit, this is just what happens when you have only one theory datapoint that is accepted by all parameters in theory. JUnit only knows about one type, so I think your only way out is to make a parameters supplier that generates a cartesian product of a given length.

Comment: I guess, there's also a manual creation of a cartesian product, but I won't suggest that one.